# Find yaw, roll and pitch angles of the face from live webcam stream

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, face-detection

I need to find the yaw, roll and pitch angles from a webcam stream of a face. I used opencv to get face landmarks and detect the face. Can someone help or guide me on how to find and print those angles?
I am using Visual Studio 2022 (community).

```
Ptr<Facemark> facemark; //mark detection
CascadeClassifier faceDetector; //face detection

void process(Mat img, Mat imgcol) {
    vector<Rect> faces;
    faceDetector.detectMultiScale(img, faces);
    Mat imFace;
    if (faces.size() != 0) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
        {
            cv::rectangle(imgcol, faces[i], Scalar(255, 0, 0));
            imFace = imgcol(faces[i]);
            resize(imFace, imFace, Size(imFace.cols * 5, imFace.rows * 5));
            faces[i] = Rect(faces[i].x = 0, faces[i].y = 0, faces[i].width * 5,
                (faces[i].height) * 5);
        }
        vector< vector<Point2f> > shapes;
        if (facemark->fit(imFace, faces, shapes))   
        {
            for (unsigned long i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++) {
                for (unsigned long k = 0; k < shapes[i].size(); k++) {
                    cv::circle(imFace, shapes[i][k], 5, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255),FILLED);
                }
            }
        }
        namedWindow("Detected_shape");
        imshow("Detected_shape", imFace);
        waitKey(5);
    }

    else {
        cout << "Faces not detected." << endl;
    }

}

int main()
{
    facemark = FacemarkLBF::create();
    facemark->loadModel("lbfmodel.yml");
    faceDetector.load("D:/opencv/build/install/etc/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");
    cout << "Loaded model" << endl;

    VideoCapture cap(1);  //capture image
    int initialized = 0;

    for (;;)
    {
        if (!cap.isOpened()) {
           cout << "Video Capture Fail" << endl;
            break;
        }

        else {
            Mat img;   //image containers
            Mat imgbw;
            cap >> img;   //image from webcam

            resize(img, img, Size(460, 460), 0, 0, INTER_LINEAR_EXACT);
            cvtColor(img, imgbw, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            process(imgbw, img);
            namedWindow("Live", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
            imshow("Live", img);
            waitKey(5);
        }
    }
}
```

The code includes what I could do so far. It detects a face and landmarks. How do I find the angles and print them from this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow! Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)! Maybe also consult ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: As it currently stands, the question provides too little details on what you have done exactly so far (some example code might help there), and where exactly it is that you have a problem.

Comment: @codeling ty for your input. I added the code I compiled so far to help others better understand where I stand atp.

Comment: keyword: `solvePnP` and you need a 3D model for those landmarks to make solvePnP work. much has been written on face/head pose estimation